# How to clear sessionStorage on button click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, session-storage

In my Django app I am storing certain key data into session storage. I am able to clear the data using `sessionStorage.clear()` as shown here:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

**Now is there a way to clear session storage on button click?**

Comment: try `onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 0):

U can Do

HTML

```
<a href="{% url 'send_command' %}" class='btn btn-lg'>Button</a>
```

url.py

```
from views import send_command

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^send_command$', send_command, name='send_command'),
]
```

views.py

```
def send_command(request):
     sessionStorage.clear();
```

Comment: He said it's Django app , Is there any other language we can use for Django ?